# Mailchimp API displays ReferenceError: "REPORT_START_DATE" is not defined in Google Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Trying to connect to the Mailchimp API from the Google Sheets script editor. I've created and pasted the correct Mailchimp API-key and spreadsheet ID requested in the code below (not MY_MAILCHIMP_API_KEY_HERE and MY_SPREADSHEET_HASH_ID_HERE).

I'm getting the following error on line 8 however:

```
LINE 8
var campaignList = '/campaigns?&count='+count+'&since_send_time='+REPORT_START_DATE
```

**ReferenceError: "REPORT_START_DATE" is not defined. (line 8, file "Code")**

```
function chimpCampaigns() {
var API_KEY = 'MY_MAILCHIMP_API_KEY_HERE'; // MailChimp API Keyvar REPORT_START_DATE = '2019-01-01 00:00:00'; // Start Date
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MY_SPREADSHEET_HASH_ID_HERE');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CampaignData");
var dc = API_KEY.split('-')[1];
var api = 'https://'+ dc +'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0';
var count = 500; // Max rows to return
var campaignList = '/campaigns?&count='+count+'&since_send_time='+REPORT_START_DATE
var options = {"headers": {"authorization": 'apikey '+API_KEY}};
var apiCall = function(endpoint){
apiResponseCampaigns = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api+endpoint,options);
json = JSON.parse(apiResponseCampaigns);
return json
}
var campaigns = apiCall(campaignList);
var total = campaigns.total_items;
var campaignData = campaigns.campaigns;
if (campaignData) {
sheet.clear(); // Clear all data in Spreadsheet
// Create the Header
sheet.appendRow(["Sent Time", "Campaign ID", "Campaign Title", "Subject Line", "Emails Sent", "Abuse Reports", "Unsubscribed", "Unsubscribe Rate", "Hard Bounces", "Soft Bounces", "Bounces Total", "Syntax Errors", "Forwards Count", "Forwards Opens", "Opens Total", "Unique Opens", "Open Rate", "Last Open", "Clicks Total", "Unique Clicks","Unique Subscriber Clicks", "Click Rate", "Last Click"]);
}
for (i=0; i< campaignData.length; i++){
  var c = campaignData[i];
  var cid = c.id;
  var title = c.title;
  var subject = c.subject;
  var send_time = c.send_time;
  if (send_time){
    apiResponseReports = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://'+ dc+'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/'+cid,options);
    reports = JSON.parse(apiResponseReports);
    reportsSendTime = reports.send_time; 
    if(reportsSendTime){ 
        var campaign_title = c.settings.title;
var subject_line = c.settings.subject_line;
var emails_sent = reports.emails_sent;
var abuse_reports = reports.abuse_reports;
var unsubscribed = reports.unsubscribed;
var unsubscribe_rate = unsubscribed/emails_sent;
var hard_bounces = reports.bounces.hard_bounces;
var soft_bounces = reports.bounces.soft_bounces;
var bounces = hard_bounces+soft_bounces;
var syntax_errors = reports.bounces.syntax_errors;
var forwards_count = reports.forwards.forwards_count;
var forwards_opens = reports.forwards.forwards_opens;
var opens_total = reports.opens.opens_total;
var unique_opens = reports.opens.unique_opens;
var open_rate = reports.opens.open_rate;
var last_open = reports.opens.last_open;
var clicks_total = reports.clicks.clicks_total;
var unique_clicks = reports.clicks.unique_clicks;
var unique_subscriber_clicks = reports.clicks.unique_subscriber_clicks;
var click_rate = reports.clicks.click_rate;
var report = [send_time, cid, campaign_title, subject_line,
emails_sent, abuse_reports, unsubscribed, unsubscribe_rate, hard_bounces, soft_bounces, bounces, syntax_errors, forwards_count, forwards_opens, opens_total, unique_opens, open_rate, last_open, clicks_total, unique_clicks, unique_subscriber_clicks, click_rate];
sheet.appendRow(report);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: You've got `REPORT_START_DATE` commented out; uncomment it.

Comment: Thanks! That wasn't the problem however I hadn't changed the var sheet to the correct correlating tab.

Comment: Your error is ""REPORT_START_DATE" is not defined. So, what value was/is "REPORT_START_DATE"? I'd suggest a logger statement after `var campaignList = ...` to display the value of the variable "campaignList".